# Yet Another Situation with Vertical Centering but Nested in Anchor and Span

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, absolute, fluid

Searched high and low and every situation out there does not work for me.  How can I vertically center the text within each list item?  I do need to keep the link (clickable area) covering the background image.

HTML

```
<section>
  <ul>
  <li><a id="monday" href="_monday.html"><span>Monday</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="tuesday" href="_tuesday.html"><span>Tuesday</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="wednesday" href="_wednesday.html"><span>Wednesday</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="thursday" href="_thursday.html"><span>Thursday</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="friday" href="_friday.html"><span>Friday</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="saturday" href="_saturday.html"><span>Saturday</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="sunday" href="_sunday.html"><span>Sunday</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="printAll" href="_week.html"><span>Print All Specials</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS (some version of it - I'm still learning lots :)

```
    section {
    max-width:86.029411764%;
    margin: -6px auto auto auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }   

    section ul {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    }

    section li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: url(_images/daybg_06.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-top: 14.95%;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    }

    section ul li a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    }

    section ul li a span {


    }
```

Here is updated link - http://jsbin.com/ExEHAL/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: any chance of getting it visually?

Comment: @skip405 not at this time.  I am working on this small piece of a bigger project, sorry :(

Comment: I understand that, but can you reproduce the issue using jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: Let's try this - http://jsbin.com/ExEHAL/1/edit?html,css,output it shows the list items not centered horizontally which it is in my browser but I also am using an image there instead of the color blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, I haven't validated or anything but this does keep the text centered exactly like I needed.  Thanks again for previous help, it is all greatly appreciated!

Same HTML

CSS

```
section {
position: relative;
width: 86.029411764%;
height: 100%;
margin: -6px auto 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

section ul {
list-style-type: none;
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-width: 200px;
margin: .6rem auto 1.2rem auto;
height: 100%;
font-size: 0;
}

section ul li {
position: relative;
width: 45%;
max-width: 481px;
display: inline-block;
background: url(_images/daybg.png) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
margin: auto 2.5% auto 2.5%;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 9%;
}

section ul li a {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;

}

section ul li a span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
line-height: 0;
font-size: 1.1rem;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for any and all advice.  I did try cover and it wouldn't show the entire image so I went with contain.  I have not checked any of this cross-browser and I'm sure it will take a while to learn what methods are best for all browsers vs just latest Chrome.  Thank you again!

Comment: I didn't notice this before but this actually cuts off the edge of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like my own answer )) But I find it the best in the current situation.

```
section ul li a span {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
section ul li a span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

The first example is not centered. The second example is a bit closer to what is needed. The only this to note that `margin-top: -10px` means the element's height / 2

Comment: The padding top is keeping the aspect ration of my fluid image.  The absolute of the anchor is so the clickable area is spread across the image.

Comment: Ok, no more critics from my side then. If you understand what you are doing - that's another story... sometimes people just use random properties to accomplish the visual look without proper understanding.

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, I am learning as I go and certainly don't know what I'm doing.  Those were the only answers I found for those other problems :)  I'm using this in a fluid responsive approach, fluid down til breakpoints then responsive.  I am open to any and all criticism.

Comment: Yeah with no height defined this doesn't work for me.  I tried half of the padding top value just to see but that is aspect ratio preserving off of width and I didn't expect much.

Comment: But have you tried `margin-top: -10px;`? If it's text that needs to be in the middle it should me at least better than nothing ))

Comment: It won't stay centered though for fluid design with the fixed amount px unfortunately.